# What is the best place for hosting Facebook Messenger Bot code?

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, lambda, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a question that might be simple for you to decide, but I am quite new to this.

What do you think is the best way **to host Node.js code for Messenger Bot**?

I am considering to use AWS Lambda, but it seems quite robust to me. Isn't there any easier way?

Thanks.

Comment: Why lambda is robust for you. Why? You are a software engineer , and lambda is just a function as a service. Go ahead and no worry.

Comment: I assume/you assume you worked as front-end developer at 2013 . So go ahead and no worry.

Comment: @Abdennour. I don't think the SO meant "reliable". I think that he meant "difficult".

Comment: Yeah exactly. I have no previous experience with AWS. That's why I asked about some alternative. But if you think it is not difficult, I will dig deeper into it.

Comment: i prefer digitalocean, because it´s not that difficult but you can do pretty much whatever you want. here´s a referral link if you want to get some credits for testing (and i get some too): https://m.do.co/c/07d8a2d61f34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise you to try out [Heroku](https://heroku.com/). I use the GitHub auto-deployment integration and it works like a charm! Look for the 'Deploy to Heroku' badge on some popular Messenger bot node.js repos on Github, and it literally does all the work for you!

Good luck.